# How do I automate certain tasks with Python?

Tags: python, astronomy

I'm working on my science fair project as much as I can, but the deadline is approaching. I basically am just performing this really repetitive task inside of a program with thousands of astronomic images.

Is there a universal way to automate program tasks with Python? I've created something similar to this in the past (code below). This program basically just told a program (SAOIMAGEDS9) to open files from a specific folder and save them as a specific file type in a new folder.

```
import os
import subprocess
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 700, height = 700,)
canvas1.pack()

target_directory = 'C:/dir/' # change this as required
target_write_directory = 'C:/dir/'

def begin_conversion(): #function first conversion
    zipped_files = [x for x in os.listdir(target_directory)if x.lower().endswith('.fits.fz')]
    for filename in zipped_files:
        print(os.path.abspath(filename))
        subprocess.call([r'C:/SAOImageDS9/ds9.exe', os.path.abspath(filename), '-savefits', os.path.abspath(target_write_directory + filename[:-3]), '-exit'])

createBatButton = tk.Button (root, text = '          convert              ', command = begin_conversion)
canvas1.create_window(350,320, window = convert)

root.mainloop()
```

So I use tkinter for a GUI in the program above so that I can just leave it open and press the button whenever I need to. I don't want to use tkinter this time, so how should I approach this new task on a windows machine?

Below is what I have so far

```
import os
import subprocess

target_directory = 'C:/read_directory/' # change this as required make sure to leave a / at the end.
target_write_directory = 'C:/write_directory/' # also change this as needed and leave a / at the end.

def automateProcess(): #Execute the astrometrica commands.
    targetFiles = [x for x in os.listdir(target_directory)if x.lower().endswith('.fits')]
    for filename in targetFiles:
        subprocess.call([r'C:/Astrometrica.exe', os.path.abspath(filename), '-load','-', '-savefits', os.path.abspath(target_write_directory + filename[:-3]), '-exit'])

automateProcess()

root.mainloop()
```

Rather than -savefits  and -exit I need to perform a multitude of very specific and tedious tasks within the program "Astrometrica"

Comment: You mean something like a "macro" (a repetitive sequence of keystrokes?) once program Astrometrica is open for every file?

Comment: there is no universl method. Some program may have options to run in console and other may not have it - and you can't force them to get options. In some situations you may try to use `PyAutoGUI`, `pynput` or similar to control mouse and keyboard and send key/mouse events to system and it may send them to active program - if it is GUI program.

Comment: This is too vague/broad, and possibly off topic. See: [help/on-topic].

Comment: You should be more specific about what do you want to automatize and how: Do you want to execute some function every certain time, like once an hour? Or every time it receives an external input, in an asynchronous way? Should the input be manual (pressing a button) every time or completely automatic? Should you execute your function once or several time in a loop?

Comment: @jcf I recommend you view this other post I created. This post was intentionally meant to be somewhat vague as I hadn't received any help when going into specific detail. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59385450/how-do-i-automate-the-usage-of-a-program-in-python)